# Text field created went missing upon clicking on it

Tags: jquery

I'm experimenting with jquery and I've encountered problem after playing around with a script i found online.

After typing in the number of text fields to create, the text fields appeared but disappear once i click on them. I really appreciate some help on this. Thanks!

```
$(function() {

var input = $('<input type="text" />');
var newFields = $('');

$('#qty').bind('blur keyup change', function() {
    var n = this.value || 0;
    if (n+1) {
        if (n > newFields.length) {
            addFields(n);
        } else {
            removeFields(n);
        }
    }
});

function addFields(n) {
    for (i = newFields.length; i < n && i<20; i++) {
        var somestr = "Length of Sample ";
        var num = i+1;
        var newInput = input.clone();
        newFields = newFields.add(newInput);           
        $('#newFields').append(somestr+num+":");
        newInput.appendTo('#newFields');
    }
}

function removeFields(n) {
    var removeField = newFields.slice(n).remove();
        $('#newFields').remove();
    newFields = newFields.not(removeField);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only bind your function to `blur`, which is when the input field is no longer selected

```
$('#qty').bind('blur', function() {
    ... The function ...
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RrXFf/)

After a bit of playing around with it I found that it had some errors in removing some objects after the first remove. I messed with it for a while but then decided it'd be easiest to not have a separate `add` and `remove` but rather just a `set` method. [Check out the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RrXFf/1/), it works perfectly. The only downside is that you don't retain the old inputs (so their fields will be empty each refresh)

Comment: thanks for the help. After replacing the initial number with another number, the text field doesn't get created. Thanks again!

Comment: I realize what you were saying, if you input a number, click off, then input a smaller number it breaks. Fixing it now

Comment: @user3338267 Updated my answer with a work around for the remove errors

Comment: @ Zach Saucier Thanks! Was playing around with your answer but i screwed up again. I've created a table (<Table><TR><TD>Label</TD><TD><input id='qty'/>    <div id='newFields'></div></TD></TR></table>) and I've tried editing the script so that each text field created will have:

- it's "label" inserted into the first column and will be a row on its own

- the input in the second column and on the same row as the corresponding label. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @user3338267 That would require changing the javascript a fair bit to append it to multiple `td`s and is out of the scope of this question. Try it for yourself for a bit, sleep on it, and then ask a new question here on StackOverflow if you're stuck (:

Comment: hi there! I've played around and came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/RrXFf/98/. It looks fine if i set the border to 1, but the label appears to be "floating" if i set the border to 0. Can i trouble you to take a look at it? Thanks!

Comment: @user3338267 Changing the border of what to 0?

Comment: Hi there. <table border=1> in html. Thanks!

Comment: @user3338267 What's the expected behavior when you change the border to 0?

Comment: Hi. I just wanted the labels to be aligned with the input fields, be it with border or not.  thanks!

Comment: @user3338267 I'm still not understanding exactly what you want. Do you mean how the second column shifts over when new inputs are added?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Maybe you can type "10" into the input for quantity in http://jsfiddle.net/RrXFf/101/ and you will realise that the alignment of each label and input textfield is not the same.

Comment: @user3338267 [**How's this look?**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/RrXFf/102/) I just had to add some `margin-bottom` and `display:block` to the left hand column